# running an executable in its own working directory

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I added a button to my gvim toolbar which runs a `.sh` file. The `.sh` file runs scons to build my c++ application in the /build subdirectory and runs it. The problem is that when the application is running, its current working directory is the folder that contains the `.sh` file (not the applications /build subdirectory)! **So how do I run a built c++ applications executable (linux) from a `.sh` file, so that its working directory would be the folder which contains executable?**

Comment: In your shell script, couldn't you just `cd` to the directory containing the executable before running it?

Comment: "No" — would you like to defend why the obvious solution won't work for your use case?

Comment: Can you not pass the directory of the current buffer to the script? In `vim`, this is `%` is the current buffer, and `%:h` is the path containing that file. From there, you could just `cd` up until you find a `SConstruct` file.

Comment: I don't know why, but `cd` does not work in the shell script. If I write two lines: `cd build` and `exec_test` I get a message that exec_test was not found

Comment: You might use `pwd` to help debug where your shell script thinks it is. You are using a shell script (launched from vim) and not vim command, right? (`vim` itself has a `cd` command. (`:help :cd`).)

Comment: Along that same vein, could we see: 1. The command used to add the toolbar item (and thus run the script) 2. the script itself?

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
 cd $(dirname "$0")
 ./exec_test
```

Note, you ***need*** `./exec_test`, not `exec_test` unless the directory is actually already in `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of something similar (I don't use `scons`.)

I add my toolbar icon with:

```
:amenu ToolBar.mytool :!/home/me/code/misc/foo.sh "%"
```

For me, when I click this, `vim` runs the script in the same working directory as `vim`.

`foo.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# You should see the name of your file.
# It might just be "my_file.c"
echo "$1"
# This will tell you where your script is current cd'd to.
pwd

# `cd` to where the file passed on the command line is:
cd "$(dirname "$1")"

# Look for "CMakeLists.txt"
# You only need this loop if your build file / program might be up a few directories.
# My stuff tends to be:
# / - project root
#   CMakeLists.txt
#   src/
#     foo.c
#     bar.c
while true; do
    # We found it.
    if [[ -e "CMakeLists.txt" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    # We didn't find it. If we're at the root, just abort.
    if [[ "`pwd -P`" = "/" ]]; then
        echo "Couldn't find CMakeLists.txt." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    cd ..
done

# I do builds in a separate directory.
cd build && make
```

You'd replace `CMakeLists.txt` with `SConstruct`, and the last `cd build && make` with `scons`, or something appropriate to `scons`.